# TinyMCE generating random <g> tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, wysiwyg

After saving some page content in the TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor, I've found that the following HTML  tag is peppered throughout the content:

```
<g class="gr_ gr_283 gr-alert gr_spell gr_run_anim gr_inline_cards ContextualSpelling ins-del multiReplace" id="283" data-gr-id="283"></g>
```

It will often wrap itself around words or sentences. It doesn't change the appearance of the content as the classes are not referenced in any stylesheets, however it has interfered with the occasional wildcards that are meant to be auto-replaced with content.

I couldn't find any answers online, however googling the class names has returned a number of results where similar  tags are generated into the plain text of a page's content.

Anybody know why this occurs and if there is a way to prevent it?

Comment: My guess is that it's used by TinyMCE for contextual spelling. It's used to flag words or phrases that are misspelled or may not be correct in the context in which they are used.

Comment: I am having same issue! 
It seams it was not happen before but now it is!

Comment: I am also having the same problem and looks like heaps of other websites are as well. Googling the code it inserts shows results of websites that have the same issue but all results are after 2017. My guess is that some kind of update has caused this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I [submitted this as a bug](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/3625#issuecomment-299881345) to the developers of Tinymce, they responded saying that the bug is caused with the Goolge Chrome extension [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/). After installing this extension I was able to replicate the bug and can confirm the problem is with Grammarly. Grammarly is injecting the  elements around content that has incorrect spelling/grammar.

I have implemented my own fix for this using a javascript replace function to remove the  elements.

```
function getWysiwygValue(id) {
    var value = tinyMCE.get(id).getContent();
    value = value.replace(/<\/?g[^>]*>/g, "");
    return value;
}
```

I have also contacted Grammarly to notify them of this bug, hopefully they will respond and fix the problem on their end.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution,are you using this code after Tinymce code ?

Comment: Yes, as you can see it is a custom function that returns the content within the tinymce WYSIWYG. It uses the tinymce getContent() function and then removes the <g> elements.

Comment: Did Grammarly get back to you?

Comment: Grammarly replied with a generic "We know, we are working on fixing this".